# How to validate text input in list is a multiple of 10

Tags: 2010, list, validation

I am trying to use a text column, as opposed to a number column, as I don't want any of the number formatting that automatically comes with Sharepoint.

I only want this column to accept multiples of 10. I've tried this validation formula:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER([Priority]+0), [Priority]%10=0)
```

And variants on it, but to no avail. Effectively, I need to check the input is a number, then check it is a multiple of 10. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this

> =AND(ISNUMBER(myNum+0),MOD(myNum,10)=0)